# Insert matplotlib images into a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, rdkit

**PURPOSE:** I am currently working with rdkit to colour the structures of my molecules according to `rdkit.Chem.Draw.SimilarityMaps`. Now, I would like to use the matplotlib images `SimilarityMaps` function to introduce them in a pandas dataframe and export this table in the form of an html file.

**CODE:** I tried to do that with the following code

```
import pandas as pd
from rdkit import Chem
from rdkit.Chem import Draw
from rdkit.Chem.Draw import SimilarityMaps
from rdkit.Chem.Draw import IPythonConsole #Needed to show molecules
from rdkit.Chem.Draw.MolDrawing import MolDrawing, DrawingOptions

df = pd.DataFrame({'smiles':['Nc1nc(NC2CC2)c3ncn([C@@H]4C[C@H](CO)C=C4)c3n1','CCCC(=O)Nc1ccc(OCC(O)CNC(C)C)c(c1)C(C)=O','CCN(CC)CCNC(=O)C1=CC=C(C=C1)NC(=O)C','CC(=O)NC1=CC=C(C=C1)O','CC(=O)Nc1sc(nn1)[S](N)(=O)=O']})

def getSim(smi):
    mol = Chem.MolFromSmiles(smi)
    refmol = Chem.MolFromSmiles('c1ccccc1')
    fp = SimilarityMaps.GetMorganFingerprint(mol, fpType='bv')
    fig, maxweight = SimilarityMaps.GetSimilarityMapForFingerprint(refmol, mol, SimilarityMaps.GetMorganFingerprint)
    return fig

df['map'] = df['smiles'].map(getSim)
df.to_html('/.../test.html')
```

When I open the file `test.html`, the map column contains the information "Figure (200x200)". I check if my dataframe map column contains object: it's OK in python but not in html file.

**QUESTION:** I'm not sure how to get a dataframe with images and I'd like to have the help of the community to clarify this subject.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you see as `Figure (200x200)` is the `__repr__` string of the matplotlib Figure class. It is the text representation of that python object (the same that you would see when doing `print(fig)`).

What you want instead is to have an actual image in the table. An easy option would be to save the matplotlib figure as png image, create an html tag, `<img src="some.png" />` and hence show the table.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np;np.random.seed(1)
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.colors

df = pd.DataFrame({"info" : np.random.randint(0,10,10), 
                   "status" : np.random.randint(0,3,10)})

cmap = matplotlib.colors.ListedColormap(["crimson","orange","limegreen"])

def createFigure(i):
    fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(.4,.4))
    fig.subplots_adjust(0,0,1,1)
    ax.axis("off")
    ax.axis([0,1,0,1])
    c = plt.Circle((.5,.5), .4, color=cmap(i))
    ax.add_patch(c)
    ax.text(.5,.5, str(i), ha="center", va="center")
    return fig

def mapping(i):
    fig = createFigure(i)
    fname = "data/map_{}.png".format(i)
    fig.savefig(fname)
    imgstr = '<img src="{}" /> '.format(fname)
    return imgstr


df['image'] = df['status'].map(mapping)
df.to_html('test.html', escape=False)
```

[image]

The drawback of this is that you have a lot of images saved somewhere on disk. If this is not desired, you may store the image encoded as base64 in the html file, `<img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAAN..." />`.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np;np.random.seed(1)
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.colors
from io import BytesIO
import base64

df = pd.DataFrame({"info" : np.random.randint(0,10,10), 
                   "status" : np.random.randint(0,3,10)})

cmap = matplotlib.colors.ListedColormap(["crimson","orange","limegreen"])

def createFigure(i):
    fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(.4,.4))
    fig.subplots_adjust(0,0,1,1)
    ax.axis("off")
    ax.axis([0,1,0,1])
    c = plt.Circle((.5,.5), .4, color=cmap(i))
    ax.add_patch(c)
    ax.text(.5,.5, str(i), ha="center", va="center")
    return fig

def fig2inlinehtml(fig,i):
    figfile = BytesIO()
    fig.savefig(figfile, format='png')
    figfile.seek(0) 
    # for python 2.7:
    #figdata_png = base64.b64encode(figfile.getvalue())
    # for python 3.x:
    figdata_png = base64.b64encode(figfile.getvalue()).decode()
    imgstr = '<img src="data:image/png;base64,{}" />'.format(figdata_png)
    return imgstr

def mapping(i):
    fig = createFigure(i)
    return fig2inlinehtml(fig,i)


with pd.option_context('display.max_colwidth', -1):
    df.to_html('test.html', escape=False, formatters=dict(status=mapping))
```

The output looks the same, but there are no images saved to disk.

This also works nicely in a Jupyter Notebook, with a small modification,

```
from IPython.display import HTML
# ...
pd.set_option('display.max_colwidth', -1)
HTML(df.to_html(escape=False, formatters=dict(status=mapping)))
```

[image]

Comment: Whaou ... Thanks a lot. Your answer is very cool. I found approximately the same solution but yours is more simple … I take :)