# Convert .png file to pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, image, numpy, opencv

I have a 512x512 .png radar image name `png_image`

I also have a csv `rainfall_colour_table` with the following headers `B, G, R, rainfall_mm`, that I can use to link colour values to rainfall intensity values.

What is the best way to read `png_image` and convert it to a 512x512 Pandas DataFrame where the values are `rainfall_mm` from `rainfall_colour_table`.

I have used the following approach.

```
from urllib.request import urlopen, Request
import cv2
import os
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

# NOTE: the ftp sourve of the png changes every 30 min
# get any current .png file name from the website ftp://ftp.bom.gov.au/anon/gen/radar//
# and set the below variable
file_name = 

# get connection to file
input_url = "ftp://ftp.bom.gov.au/anon/gen/radar//" + file_name
req = Request(input_url)

req_html = urlopen(req).read()

# read file
radar_image = np.fromstring(req_html, np.uint8)  # read byte image
radar_image = cv2.imdecode(radar_image, cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)  # convert to numppy array

# OS agnostic relative file path
# get the current directory path
base_dir = os.path.dirname(__file__)

# OS agnostic relative file path
# load colour to mm/hr concurrency table
rainfall_colour_table = os.path.join(os.sep, base_dir, 'sample_data', 'radar_colours.csv')
rainfall_colour_df = pd.read_csv(rainfall_colour_table)
rainfall_colour_df.set_index(['B', 'G', 'R'], inplace=True)

# switch colours with rain intensity
radar_df = pd.DataFrame(rainfall_colour_df.loc[list(map(tuple, pin))].rainfall.values for pin in radar_image)
radar_df.columns = ['pixel_col_' + str(col) for col in radar_df.columns]
```

The rainfall_colour_table.csv

```
colour_id,rainfall,B,G,R
2,1.5,255,180,180
3,2.5,255,120,120
4,4,255,20,20
5,6,195,216,0
6,10,144,150,0
7,15,102,102,0
8,20,0,255,255
9,35,0,200,255
10,50,0,150,255
11,80,0,100,255
12,120,0,0,255
13,200,0,0,200
14,300,0,0,120
15,360,0,0,40
```

Comment: We could help you more easily if you gave us runnable example code with self-contained fake data.  Even if it's just a 3x3 "image".

Comment: Have you seen how they do here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47038538/insert-matplotlib-images-into-a-pandas-dataframe ?

Comment: Hope that helps

Comment: Please try to strip away all unnecessary code and let the code only be about your question.