# Insert Image of Pandas Plot in DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib

I've been wracking my brain on this issue for a couple of days now and so wanted to get the community to help. I'm using Python 3 in a Jupyter Notebook but want to eventually make this a script.

**Problem**

I have a Pandas DataFrame that has three columns (query, URL, Trend). All of the data is working. I'm even able to produce the plot images for each query; however, I can't get the images of the Trend plots to display in the Trends column of my DataFrame. It just shows `AxesSubplot(0.125,0.125;0.775x0.755)`. There are no error messages (although, I've rangled a few).

**What I've tried**

I've taken a look at fig.savefig() and this seems to be close to what I need but not 100% sure how to make that work in my situation as it outputs all the plots and I need one plot per query.

I've also given [this solution on Stack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47038538/insert-matplotlib-images-into-a-pandas-dataframe) a go but I haven't been able to implement it for my code (it's close though).

[This article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53468558/adding-image-to-pandas-dataframehttps://) is also very close to the implementation I'm looking for results-wise (and my current implementation) but I don't know how to get the HTML URL of the image of a plot I just created. As well, ideally, the image doesn't need to be saved as this is likely to be a daily report going out via email.

**Results so far**

Dataframe

Query   URL Trend

0   Margaret Trudeau    https://montreal.ctvnews.ca/margaret-trudeau-d...   AxesSubplot(0.125,0.125;0.775x0.755)

1   Nick Cordero    https://people.com/theater/nick-cordero-doctor...   AxesSubplot(0.125,0.125;0.775x0.755)

And, so on.

These are the Trend plots that come out of the code just below the DataFrame.

[image: Image of trend plot output]

[image: Image of trend plot output]

And, so on.

It appears everything works but...

**Expected result**

The DataFrame should be the same as above but I want `AxesSubplot(0.125,0.125;0.775x0.755)` to be an image of the trend plot.

**Current Code**

```
from googlesearch import search

import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from pytrends.request import TrendReq

pytrend = TrendReq()

def trending_searches(geo):
    geo_lower = str.lower(geo) # Need geolocation to be lowercase to work
    df = pytrend.trending_searches(pn=geo_lower)

    queries = [] # Hold all processed queries

    for index, row in df.iterrows():
        i = str(row)
        j = str.strip(i, '0    ')
        k = j.split("\n", 1)[0]
        queries.append(k)

    # Gets the trend data 
    trend = pd.DataFrame(get_trend(queries))

    # Gets the first URL from each query on Google
    urls = pd.DataFrame(get_urls(queries))

    # column lable
    trend.columns = ["Trend"]
    urls.columns = ["URL"]
    df.columns = ['Query']

    #Concat all into one dataframe
    result = pd.concat([df, urls, trend], axis=1)

    #html = result.to_html() #Convert to HTML for emails

    return result #html

def get_trend(kw: list) -> list:

    query = kw

    # Get trend data
    my_results_list = []
    for j in query:    
        pytrend.build_payload(kw_list=[j])
        df = pytrend.interest_over_time()
        my_results_list.append(df)

    # Plot trend data
    plots = []
    for i in range(len(my_results_list)):
        if my_results_list[i].empty == True: # To mitigate queries that have no data
            plots.append("No data avaiable")
        else:
            plot = my_results_list[i].plot(kind='line', figsize=(5,1), sharex=True)
            plots.append(plot)

    return plots

def get_urls(kw: list) -> list:

    query = kw

    my_results_list = []
    for j in query:    
        for i in search(j,        # The query you want to run
                    tld = 'ca',  # The top level domain
                    lang = 'en',  # The language
                    num = 10,     # Number of results per page
                    start = 0,    # First result to retrieve
                    stop = 1,  # Last result to retrieve
                    pause = 2.0,  # Lapse between HTTP requests
                   ):

            my_results_list.append(i)

    return my_results_list

trending_searches('Canada')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once you have the `fig` already built, you have to transform it to binary, and then store into a var as a value

```
buf = io.BytesIO()
fig.savefig(buf, format='png')
buf.seek(0)
string = base64.b64encode(buf.read())
```

Then you have to aggregate the HTML tags which corresponds to output an image

```
uri = 'data:image/png;base64,' + urllib.parse.quote(string)
html = '<img src = "%s"/>' % uri
```

To simulate your dataframe I've created 3 lists and appended each result to it as follows:

```
for i in range(10):
    ...
    query.append(i+1)
    url.append("google.com")
    trend.append(html)

df = pd.DataFrame({"query": query,"url": url,"trend":trend})
df.head()
```

[image]

Then I did the `dataframe.to_html(escape=False)` and it did result in the HTML with the images.

[image]

Obviously I am using here jupyter, but with the HTML built you should be able to print it as you were doing without further issues.

So finally, I arrived at the code below:

```py
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import urllib, urllib.parse, base64, io, base64
from IPython.core.display import display, HTML

# simulate dataframe
query = []
url = []
trend = []
for i in range(10):

    #save fig
    plt.plot(np.random.rand(5));
    fig = plt.gcf();

    #store it as binary
    buf = io.BytesIO()
    fig.savefig(buf, format='png')
    buf.seek(0)
    string = base64.b64encode(buf.read())

    #complement with HTML tags
    uri = 'data:image/png;base64,' + urllib.parse.quote(string)
    html = '<img src = "%s"/>' % uri

    #clear matplotlib's cache
    plt.clf()

    #append results
    query.append(i+1)
    url.append("google.com")
    trend.append(html)

#build df
df = pd.DataFrame({"query": query,"url": url,"trend":trend})
#parse into html
html = df.to_html(escape=False)
```

Could you check whether it worked? :)

Comment: Hey Caio! This is really helpful. I'm having a similar issue to my original problem. So, I tried your code as stand-alone, which worked! I then integrated it into my code. It's now putting the <img src=> value into the dataframe but won't display the image. After a few trials, I added plt.show() to ensure a plot was being created for each row. Yup, it is. Then tried calling the function wrapped in the display HTML. display(HTML(trending_searches('Canada'))). Not sure what I'm missing but we're obviously close!

Comment: I figured it out. Need to add escape=False when calling the to_html()

Comment: How to save it as .xlsx?

Comment: From Pandas dataframe there's the option to save as an excel `df.to_excel('path/file.xlsx')`. Not sure though whether it will properly display the images.